# write unit test case for a method which is returning promise in the form of array using jasmine karma

Tags: angular, unit-testing, mocking, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am new to unit test cases. I have a method called 'loadEsriModules' which is calling from ngOnInIt(). below is the sample code for the same.

```
ngOnInit() {
    debugger
    this.loadEsriModules().then(() => {
      this.mapManager.getMapInstance().subscribe(mapInstance => {
        debugger
        if (mapInstance) {
          this.mapInstance = mapInstance;
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Code of loadEsriModules Method. Application is working fine and while running unit test case code is throwing error and jump to catch block.

```
 loadEsriModules() {
    try {
     return  this.esriLoader.loadModules([
        "esri/layers/GeoJSONLayer",
        "esri/Graphic"
      ]).then((res)=>{
        console.log("log here");
        console.log(res);
        debugger
        const [GeoJSONLayer, Graphic] = res;
        this.geoJsonLayer = GeoJSONLayer;
        this.graphic = Graphic;
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error loading Esri tile module", error);
    }
  }
```

**in promise it is returning below response in the form of array while running the application.**
[Response logged in console][1]
actual object after expanding console log

```
[ƒ, ƒ]
0: ƒ d()arguments: nullcaller: nulllength: 0name: "d"prototype: a {declaredClass: 'esri.layers.GeoJSONLayer', constructor: ƒ}[[FunctionLocation]]: 4.16:188[[Prototype]]: ƒ a(d)[[Scopes]]: Scopes[5]
1: ƒ d()generateUID: ƒ ()arguments: nullcaller: nulllength: 0name: "d"prototype: e {declaredClass: 'esri.Graphic', constructor: ƒ}[[FunctionLocation]]: 4.16:188[[Prototype]]: ƒ e()[[Scopes]]: Scopes[5]length: 2[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

So i want to write the unit test case for the same. Below are the things i have tried but throwing error as i mentioned above.

```
spyOn(esriLoaderService,"loadModules").and.callFake(() => {
      return of([{},{}]);
     });
```

The problem is that i don't know how to create the mock data for this kind of array response which is having functions.

let me know if any additional information required.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjAUL.png

Answer (score 0):

Try changing these lines:

```
spyOn(esriLoaderService,"loadModules").and.callFake(() => {
      return of([{},{}]);
     });
```

To:

```
spyOn(esriLoaderService,"loadModules").and.callFake(() => {
      return Promise.resolve([{},{}]);
     });
```

`of` is for `Observables` and `Promise.resolve` should do the trick for `Promises`.